# Scopt for complex types

Tags: scala, scopt

```
import scopt.Read.stringRead._
case class Config(
    kwargs: Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]] = Map()
)

  val parser: OptionParser[Config] = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("test") {
    head("Test Server", "v1")
   
    opt[Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]]("kwargs")
      .valueName("k1=v1,k2=v2...")
      .action((x, c) => c.copy(kwargs = x))
      .text("other arguments")
```

What would be the value name and text for it?
k1=v1,k2=v2... is valid for map of string.

```
       .valueName(???)
          .action((x, c) => ??)
          .text("other arguments")
```

Comment: Do you want to add all values as a single parameter or append them somehow? Because it affects if you need to somehow update map with each parameter or if you need to create a custom `Read` instance.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok all of them